# error while running pacbio + dada2 workflow

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I ran those below commands and I got an error attached below can you please suggest me possible solution for it?

```
# Save your dada2 object and taxonomy assignment into RDS files for future use

saveRDS(dd, file.path(path.rds, "sam3.rds"))
saveRDS(tax, file.path(path.rds, "sam3tax_Silva138.1.rds"))

# Load your saved dada2 object and taxonomy assignment from RDS files

dd \<- readRDS(file.path(path.rds, "sam3.rds"))
tax \<- readRDS(file.path(path.rds, "sam3tax_Silva138.1.rds"))

# dada2:::pfasta(dd, id=tax\[,6\])

uniquesToFasta(dd, file.path(path.rds, "LRAS_sam3_ASVs.fa"), ids=paste0(tax\[,"Genus"\], ";size=", dd$denoised, ";"))
is.ec \<- tax\[,"Genus"\] %in% "Escherichia"
uniquesToFasta(dd$clustering\[is.ec,\], file.path(path.rds, "sam3_Ecoli.fa"), ids=paste0("Ecoli", seq(sum(is.ec)), "\_HMP"))

# BLAST against nt excluding uncultured/environmental sequences (checkbox)

# BLAST against nt excluding uncultured/environmental sequences (checkbox)
```

> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the argument
> 'object' in selecting a method for function 'writeFasta': invalid
> class “ShortRead” object: sread() and id() length mismatch: 0, 2

I want to go forward but I am facing some issues related to objects and class I need to solve it but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your variable "tax" and see if "Escherichia" exists. More than likely, you'll actually see "Esherichica/Shigella" instead. If that's the case, there likely is a line that says:

```
tax[,"Genus"] <- gsub("Escherichia/Shigella", "Escherichia", tax[,"Genus"]) 
# Reformat to be compatible with other data sources
```

so replace "Escherichia/Shigella" with "Esherichica/Shigella" so the line correctly substitutes and proceed through your code.

I believe I'm running the same script.